# Gradle : How to ignore failure to resolve a specific dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

```
dependencies {
    test "com.test:testA:1.0@jar"
    test "com.test:testB:1.0@jar"
}


task('collectArtifacts', type: Copy) {
     from project.configurations.test
     into 'artifacts/'
}
```

Assuming the artifact testA is missing and testB is available

When I use ./gradlew collectArtifacts it obviously complains saying 
"> Could not find com.test:testA:1.0".

How can I ask gradle to:

- If testA is available all is good, gradle downloads both testA and testB
- If testA is not available I want gradle to ignore resolution failure for testA dependency and move ahead to download testB.

Comment: Depending on the binary repository product you are using, you could call its RESTful API to determine if a dependency exists up-front.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a bit counter-intuitively, you can use `getResolvedConfiguration()` in combination with `getLenientConfiguration()` to retrieve a configuration that does not fail if some of the references are not resolvable.

```
task('collectArtifacts', type: Copy) {
     from project.configurations.test.resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration.getFiles(Specs.satisfyAll())
     into 'artifacts/'
}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#getResolvedConfiguration()).

Comment: this gives me -  Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: file for class: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingLenientConfiguration.


However a slight modification worked for me :
`project.configurations.test.resolvedConfiguration.lenientConfiguration.getFiles(Specs.satisfyAll())`

Comment: Ah, right, `files` is not a property. Edited the answer to include this. If it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following. Not sure what exactly `test` is, so I'm assuming it is a typo for `testCompile`.

```
task('collectArtifacts', type: Copy) {
    from project.configurations.testCompile.findAll { it.exists() }
    into 'artifacts/'
}
```

Comment: 'test' here is a configuration name, just a name its not a typo for testCompile
I still get the same error with this